# Connot GET / -> After Update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

After i update ionic + angular + capacitor i got some errors which I was able to fix. But now.. when i run `ionic capacitor run android -l --external` the App got opening, and display `Connot GET /` when i open the Browser on my phone and type the Servers address, its fine.

Before the update, ionic starts android studio. Now i can select the device in the CLI.

On build, i got no errors.

```
$ ionic capacitor run android -l --external
? Which device would you like to target? Xiaomi Mi Note 10 Lite (918e0fc4)
> capacitor sync android
[capacitor] ✔ Copying web assets from www to android/app/src/main/assets/public in 614.64ms
[capacitor] ✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in android/app/src/main/assets in 1.15ms
[capacitor] (node:13183) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /home/Mitch/Dev/Cremer/belimo-qr/node_modules/tslib/package.json.
[capacitor] Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
[capacitor] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[capacitor] [info] Found 4 Cordova plugins for android:
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-ble-central@1.4.1
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-bluetoothle@6.6.1
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@5.0.0
[capacitor] ✔ copy android in 895.29ms
[capacitor] ✔ Updating Android plugins in 75.90ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 2 Capacitor plugins for android:
[capacitor]        @capacitor-community/barcode-scanner@1.2.1
[capacitor]        @capacitor/browser@1.0.7
[capacitor] [info] Found 4 Cordova plugins for android:
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-ble-central@1.4.1
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-bluetoothle@6.6.1
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2
[capacitor]        cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@5.0.0
[capacitor] ✔ update android in 214.73ms
[capacitor] [info] Sync finished in 1.115s
[WARN] Multiple network interfaces detected!
       
       You will be prompted to select an external-facing IP for the dev server that your device or emulator can access.
       Make sure your device is on the same Wi-Fi network as your computer. Learn more about Live Reload in the docs[1].
       
       To bypass this prompt, use the --public-host option (e.g. --public-host=192.168.178.33). You can alternatively
       bind the dev server to a specific IP (e.g. --host=192.168.178.33).
       
       [1]: https://ion.link/livereload-docs
       
? Please select which IP to use: 192.168.178.33 (wlan0)
> ng run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8101
[ng] Warning: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
[ng] locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
[ng] 
[ng] Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
[ng] computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
[ng] websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disable-host-check" if that's the
[ng] case.
[ng] - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
[ng] ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
[ng] Initial Chunk Files                                                     | Names             |      Size
[ng] vendor.js                                                               | vendor            |   5.18 MB
[ng] polyfills.js                                                            | polyfills         | 246.25 kB
[ng] styles.css                                                              | styles            |  37.09 kB
[ng] main.js                                                                 | main              |  25.01 kB
[ng] runtime.js                                                              | runtime           |  14.04 kB
[ng] 
[ng]                                                                         | Initial Total     |   5.50 MB
[ng] 
[ng] Lazy Chunk Files                                                        | Names             |      Size
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_swiper_bundle-28080340_js.js           | -                 | 200.28 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-datetime_3_entry_js.js             | -                 |  94.66 kB
[ng] polyfills-core-js.js                                                    | polyfills-core-js |  92.35 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-item_8_entry_js.js                 | -                 |  92.10 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-app_8_entry_js.js                  | -                 |  75.94 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-slide_2_entry_js.js                | -                 |  59.95 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-refresher_2_entry_js.js            | -                 |  50.68 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-segment_2_entry_js.js              | -                 |  40.50 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-menu_3_entry_js.js                 | -                 |  38.24 kB
[ng] src_app_home_home_module_ts.js                                          | -                 |  34.91 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-nav_2_entry_js.js                  | -                 |  34.51 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-item-option_3_entry_js.js          | -                 |  34.18 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-button_2_entry_js.js               | -                 |  33.88 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-searchbar_entry_js.js              | -                 |  33.69 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-select_3_entry_js.js               | -                 |  33.26 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-route_4_entry_js.js                | -                 |  29.58 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-range_entry_js.js                  | -                 |  28.25 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-fab_3_entry_js.js                  | -                 |  26.92 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-accordion_2_entry_js.js            | -                 |  26.54 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-tab-bar_2_entry_js.js              | -                 |  24.00 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-breadcrumb_2_entry_js.js           | -                 |  22.27 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-progress-bar_entry_js.js           | -                 |  22.00 kB
[ng] src_app_bsk-dashboard_bsk-dashboard_module_ts.js                        | -                 |  21.95 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-input_entry_js.js                  | -                 |  21.51 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-picker-internal_entry_js.js        | -                 |  21.37 kB
[ng] polyfills-dom.js                                                        | polyfills-dom     |  19.43 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-virtual-scroll_entry_js.js         | -                 |  19.33 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-textarea_entry_js.js               | -                 |  19.32 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-toggle_entry_js.js                 | -                 |  17.70 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-back-button_entry_js.js            | -                 |  17.04 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-radio_2_entry_js.js                | -                 |  16.92 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_input-shims-fef4a5fa_js.js             | -                 |  16.70 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-col_3_entry_js.js                  | -                 |  15.65 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-card_5_entry_js.js                 | -                 |  15.65 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-infinite-scroll_2_entry_js.js      | -                 |  13.93 kB
[ng] src_app_bbk-search_bbk-search_module_ts.js                              | -                 |  13.19 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-reorder_2_entry_js.js              | -                 |  12.90 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-picker-column-internal_entry_js.js | -                 |  11.96 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-checkbox_entry_js.js               | -                 |  11.48 kB
[ng] src_app_upload-csv_upload-csv_module_ts.js                              | -                 |  10.57 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-split-pane_entry_js.js             | -                 |  10.12 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-chip_entry_js.js                   | -                 |   9.87 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-tab_2_entry_js.js                  | -                 |   9.64 kB
[ng] common.js                                                               | common            |   5.85 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-avatar_3_entry_js.js               | -                 |   5.83 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_tap-click-c0be8677_js.js               | -                 |   5.76 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_keyboard-808e4e15_js.js                | -                 |   5.41 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-img_entry_js.js                    | -                 |   3.60 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-action-sheet_entry_js.js           | -                 |   3.34 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-loading_entry_js.js                | -                 |   3.31 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-popover_entry_js.js                | -                 |   3.31 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-modal_entry_js.js                  | -                 |   3.30 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-toast_entry_js.js                  | -                 |   3.30 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-alert_entry_js.js                  | -                 |   3.30 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_swipe-back-edc455e2_js.js              | -                 |   2.80 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_status-tap-4087b8c4_js.js              | -                 |   2.56 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-text_entry_js.js                   | -                 |   1.77 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-spinner_entry_js.js                | -                 |   1.52 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-backdrop_entry_js.js               | -                 |   1.40 kB
[ng] node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-ripple-effect_entry_js.js          | -                 |   1.30 kB
[ng] 
[ng] Build at: 2022-01-22T08:37:11.321Z - Hash: b2048fa2bb124900ba82 - Time: 12241ms
[ng] ✔ Compiled successfully.

[INFO] Development server running!
       
       Local: http://localhost:8101
       External: http://192.168.178.33:8101, http://192.168.178.136:8101
       
       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

> capacitor run android --no-sync --target 918e0fc4
[capacitor] ✔ Running Gradle build in 4.80s
[capacitor] ✔ Deploying app-debug.apk to 918e0fc4 in 7.37s

[INFO] App deployed to device!
       
       Development server will continue running until manually stopped.
       
       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process
```

```
$ ionic version
6.18.1

Angular CLI: 12.2.15
Node: 16.13.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: linux x64

Angular: 12.2.15
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.18
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.15
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.18
@schematics/angular             12.2.15
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.15",
    "@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner": "^1.2.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.1.2",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/ble": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/bluetooth-le": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.33.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.34.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.3",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "cordova-plugin-ble-central": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-bluetoothle": "^6.6.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "2.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "2.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.15",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.11",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

Comment: uninstall application in device and build again. if not try debugging it in chromedevtool inspect device console.\

Comment: Can you check if you still have `IonicModule.forRoot()` import in your app.module?

Answer (score 0):

ok got it:)
i open App in Browser on Desktop an saw i the console there is some error with load the Barcodescanner module...
This (and some other) dependencies needed some updates!